# How to convert a VS Code launch.json to a Visual Studio launchSettings.json for .Net Core Web Application

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I need to convert my launch.json file from VSCode into a launchSettings.json file in Visual Studios on Windows, so that I can debug with Docker. Below is my launch.json file that works in VSCode.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name":".NET Core Docker Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "composeForDebug",
        "cwd": "/app",
        "program": "/app/test.dll",
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/app": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },

        "launchBrowser": {
            "enabled": true,
            "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cmd.exe",
                "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
            },
            "osx": {
                "command": "open"
            }
        },

        "pipeTransport": {
            "pipeProgram": "/bin/bash",
            "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "pipeArgs": [ "-c", "./dockerTask.sh startDebugging" ],
            "windows": {
                "pipeProgram": "${env.windir}\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
                "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "pipeArgs": [ ".\\dockerTask.ps1", "-StartDebugging" ]
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

Below is the launchSettings.json file I have in Visual Studio on my Windows side. Its pretty much the same launchSettings.json file that gets generated when you create a new .Net Core Web Application in Visual Studio. When I try to debug with my launchSettings.json file it allows me to debug with Docker but I get an error along the lines of "The "PrepareForLaunch" task failed unexpectedly." which I think is due to some configurations I'm missing in my launchSettings.json file.

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52667/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52668"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:{ServicePort}"
    }
  }
}
```